# How to upgrade from cakephp 2.x to 4.0 directly?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to upgrade a cms which was built with cake-PHP 2.x.I am confused how to achieve that activity.

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185556/best-way-to-upgrade-a-cakephp-project-from-cakephp-2-6-2-to-3-8** Applies to 4.x too.

Comment: Somehow yes,it will give me confidence that it is possible.